# Set Random Background on List elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, background

I'm trying to make a random background for a list, where I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="grid" class="clear">
    <li>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </li>
    ...
```

The problem, is that it gives the same random background to all images, so all of them look the same. The javascript handling this function is the following

```
var bgz = ['bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg', 'bg4.jpg', 'bg5.jpg']

$(this).find("#grid li .hexagon").each(function() { $('.hexagon').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + bgz[Math.floor(Math.random() *      bgz.length)] + ')'}) })
```

Any idea on how can I fix it so each hexagon gets a different background?

And also, any idea on how can I make it change backgrounds again randomly every x number of seconds instead of having to refresh it so it changes the backgrounds while the page is already loaded?

Comment: Change `$('.hexagon').css` to `$(this).css`. You are looping over each element with `.each()`. But you are effectively changing all of them at once everytime by using the class as a selector instead of only selecting the one you're currently looping.

Comment: As for your timer, that's a simple matter of using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or for a more simple explanation: [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). All you have to do is embed your existing code inside it.

Comment: Hi icecube, how would you implement the splice() in this case? using only the $(this).css makes it reaaaally slow when i have arround 50 hexagons on screen

Comment: Please make sure you tag me with @ next time. Otherwise I won't get a notification and I usually forget about questions from a day before. Anyway, I made an example script for you here: [https://jsfiddle.net/d7tr48an/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/d7tr48an/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'hexagon' class into 'this', like below

```
$(this).find("#grid li .hexagon").each(function() { 

  $(this').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + bgz[Math.floor(Math.random() *      
  bgz.length)] + ')'}) // it will attach your css into the current div for each loop.

})
```

Not same on this one that will apply your css to all of you div with a class of 'hexagon' even if your loop is in millions.

```
$(this).find("#grid li .hexagon").each(function() { $('.hexagon').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + bgz[Math.floor(Math.random() *      bgz.length)] + ')'}) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're waiting until the document loads with `$(document).ready` before you execute this, or the elements you're trying to style won't exist yet. Then, in your `each` loop, refer to `$(this)` instead of `$(".hexagon")` so you're only referencing the *current* hexagon instead of all of them. If you don't care if some of the hexagons have the same background image, you'd do this:

```js
var bgz = ['http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg2.png', 'http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg3.png', 'http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg4.png', 'http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg5.png'];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid li .hexagon").each(function() {
    $(this).css({backgroundImage: "url('" + rando(bgz).value + "')"});
  });
});
```

```css
.hexagon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<ul id="grid" class="clear">
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want them all to be unique (so long as you've provided enough images for that to be possible), you'd create a shuffled array of the images and iterate through those- refilling the shuffled array if you run out:

```js
var bgz = ['http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg2.png', 'http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg3.png', 'http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg4.png', 'http://bytecrank.com/filebox/316d4df8eae0e148ef1237ead8118e03c7188b3aba829f9aaa42d1e53998c02856a84036913cccd69da3a6505bbf124efac43684a45fde319ab5866e114c0687/shared/stackoverflow/images/bg5.png'];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var sequence = randoSequence(bgz);
  $("#grid li .hexagon").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({backgroundImage: "url('" + sequence.pop().value + "')"});
    if(sequence.length == 0) sequence = randoSequence(bgz);
  });
});
```

```css
.hexagon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<ul id="grid" class="clear">
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I used [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) for these answers to simplify the randomness and make it more readable. `rando(myArray).value` grabs a random value from an array, and `var sequence = randoSequence(myArray)` produces a shuffled version of an array where you can access the values through `.value` - like `sequence[0].value`. Check out the site if you need more explanation. If you want to use my code, just import randojs like you would import jQuery, using this script tag:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```